# Particular category to be visible only to logged-in users

Tags: wordpress

I want to make posts in a specific category in WordPress accessible only to logged-in users.

I tried this and doesn't work.

```
function restrict_category_by_user($query) {
   if ( is_category() && ! is_user_logged_in() ) {
      $query->set( 'post_status', array('publish', 'catname') );
   }
   return $query;
}
add_filter( 'pre_get_posts', 'restrict_category_by_user' );
```